# How to run python by Notepad++

Tags: python-3.x

I want to script with python using Notepad ++ but it works strangely, actually it does not work, so I have pycharm an everything is going well but in notepad ++ when I save file with .py and click run it does not work is there a step by step instruction to follow?
I have same problem with sublime text editor so I am lucky with just Pycharm all of the others has confused me please help me.

Comment: Have you checked the paths of your interpreter in either editor?

Comment: https://silentcrash.com/2016/12/run-python-script-notepad/ Check this out

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ and sublime are text-editors and not interpreters. To run python script, you need a python interpreter. If you want to use notepad++, then write the python script in notepad++, open command prompt and run the python script from command prompt.

Assuming that you have python installrd, suppose you have created a file name "example.py" in the path "C:/Users/User/Desktop", then to run the script you will have to run the following commands:

```
$ cd "C:/Users/User/Desktop"
$ python example.py
```

Comment: Not exactly, you can tweak notepad++ a little bit, have a look at this https://silentcrash.com/2016/12/run-python-script-notepad/

Comment: Yes @anand_v.singh , I agree. I just mentioned the defaults.Thanks for sharing the link.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea Why you gave me this -1 may be someone think that he knows everything so my idle.py is not the same location to my computer and when I assign location it pops up an error 
[sorry for error message image it is unable to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDwEI.jpg)